# How to add 0 infront of week column dataframe pandas if len of column == 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
     Week  Year   new
0     43  2016 2016-10-24
1     44  2016 2016-10-31
2     51  2016 2016-12-19
3      2  2017 2017-01-09
4      5  2017 2017-01-30
5     12  2017 2017-03-20
6     52  2018 2018-12-24
7     53  2018 2018-12-31
8      1  2019 2018-12-31
9      2  2019 2019-01-07
10     5  2019 2019-01-28
11    52  2019 2019-12-23
```

How can I add 0 infront of week if the len is 1. I need to merge Year and Week together as `201702`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
df["Week"] = df.Week.astype('str').str.zfill(2)
```